# Get value of TD in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple `tr` on my page,that will have `tds` in that.Now every tr have a td that have `bd_cl` i want to get the value of `bd_cl` on click of of the link

**HTML**

```
<tr>
    <td>121</td>
    <td>111</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td bd_cl="PE">Address</td>
    <td>
        <a class="edit" title="Edit User" onclick="update(this)" href="javascript:void(0);"><img border="0" src="/icon_edit.gif"></a>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>121</td>
    <td>111</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td bd_cl="AD">Name</td>
    <td>
        <a class="edit" title="Edit User" onclick="update(this)" href="javascript:void(0);"><img border="0" src="/icon_edit.gif"></a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**jQuery**

```
function uodate (objref){
    var $parenttrobj = $(objref).closest('tr');
    alert($parenttrobj.attr("bd_cl").val());
}
```

But i am not able to get the value .Kindly help me in this

Comment: you also have uodate instead of update as the function name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrong selector for targeting clicked anchor element parents previous td element. use correct selector along with `.attr("bd_cl")` to get the value:

```
function update (objref){
  var $parenttdobj = $(objref).parent();
  alert($parenttdobj.prev().attr("bd_cl"));
}
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hmLwwo72/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code

```
$('td').each(function(){
   if($(this).hasAttr('bd_cl')){
      alert($(this).text());
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your function name.
Also, you missed your `table` tags.

If you are want to get attribute value just use `.attr('bd_cl')`

```
function update (objref){
    var $parenttrobj = $(objref).closest('tr').find('td[bd_cl]');
    alert($parenttrobj.attr("bd_cl"));
}
```

If you are want to get `td` content:

```
function update (objref){
    var $parenttrobj = $(objref).closest('tr').find('td[bd_cl]');
    alert($parenttrobj.text());
}
```

```js
function update(el) {
 var td = $(el).parent().prev();
 alert(td.attr('bd_cl'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>121</td>
    <td>111</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td bd_cl="PE">Address</td>
    <td>
        <a class="edit" title="Edit User" onclick="update(this)" href="javascript:void(0);"><img border="0" src="//placehold.it/32x32"></a>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>121</td>
    <td>111</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td bd_cl="AD">Name</td>
    <td>
        <a class="edit" title="Edit User" onclick="update(this)" href="javascript:void(0);"><img border="0" src="//placehold.it/32x32"></a>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: un defined value i am getting

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(".edit").click(function update() {
    $parenttrobj = $(this).closest('tr');
    alert($parenttrobj.find("[bd_cl]").attr("bd_cl"))
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xtz111q3/6/)**

Answer (score 0):

use `find` in jquery

```
var $parenttrobj = $(objref).closest('tr');

alert($parenttrobj.find("td").attr("bd_cl"));
```

Comment: undefined value i am getting

Comment: objref returns object or undefined make sure

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest revising your approach, slightly, to move away from the in-line event-handlers, use jQuery to assign click-handling function:

```js
function update() {
  // 'this' here is the element that was interacted with
  // at the point of event-handling being assigned.

  // find the closest ancestor <tr> element,
  // find the the <td> elements that have a 'bd_cl' attribute:
  var cell = $(this).closest('tr').find('td[bd_cl]');

  // use console.log() rather than 'alert' to log the retrieved text:
  console.log(cell.text());
}

// adds a click-handling function to the <a class="edit"> elements
// that are within <td> elements. jQuery will pass the clicked
// element to the assigned function as 'this':
$('td a.edit').on('click', update);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>121</td>
      <td>111</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td bd_cl="PE">Address</td>
      <td>
        <a class="edit" title="Edit User" href="#">
          <img border="0" src="/icon_edit.gif">
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>121</td>
      <td>111</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td bd_cl="AD">Name</td>
      <td>
        <a class="edit" title="Edit User" href="#">
          <img border="0" src="/icon_edit.gif">
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

As you were trying to find the text contained within a `<td>` element, noticeably *not* an `<input />` or `<select>` element, it has no `val()` method available to it; instead `text()` must be used.

Further, while this will work, it's worth pointing out that your HTML is invalid, due to the custom attributes you're using. Under HTML 5, however, you have access to valid `data-*` custom attributes which will validate under the HTML 5 doctype (`<doctype html>`), though it remains just as invalid (albeit backwards compatible) with HTML 4.x. So, to use `data-*` attributes:

```js
function update() {
  var cell = $(this).closest('tr').find('td[data-bd_cl]');
  console.log(cell.text());
}

$('td a.edit').on('click', update);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>121</td>
      <td>111</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td data-bd_cl="PE">Address</td>
      <td>
        <a class="edit" title="Edit User" href="#">
          <img border="0" src="/icon_edit.gif">
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>121</td>
      <td>111</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td data-bd_cl="AD">Name</td>
      <td>
        <a class="edit" title="Edit User" href="#">
          <img border="0" src="/icon_edit.gif">
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

References:

- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [Has-attribute (`[attribute]`) selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).